# How can I solve the integral equation $\pi a^2 (f(x))^2 = \int_{0}^{f(x)/a} \sqrt{(f(x))^2 -a^2t^2} \ \mathrm dt $ for the function $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, leibniz-integral-rule, integro-differential-equations

How can I solve the integral equation $\pi a^2 (f(x))^2 = \int_{0}^{f(x)/a} \sqrt{(f(x))^2 -a^2t^2} \ \mathrm dt $ for the function $f(x)$, where $a$ is a constant?

I have tried turning this into a differential equation by differentiating both sides and applying Leibniz's rule, to obtain $2\pi a^2 f(x) f'(x) = \int_{0}^{f(x)/a} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \sqrt{(f(x))^2 -a^2t^2} \ \mathrm  dt = \int_{0}^{f(x)/a} \frac{f(x) f'(x)}{\sqrt{(f(x))^2 -a^2t^2}} \ \mathrm dt$, which cancels to give $2\pi a^2 = \int_{0}^{f(x)/a} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(f(x))^2 -a^2t^2}} \ \mathrm dt$. At this point, using Leibniz's rule again results in a division by zero from plugging the bounds of the integral into the integrand. I'm not really sure what to do next, or whether there is an easy shortcut out of this mess that I'm missing. The fact that the integrand is also a function of $x$ seems to be making this problem a lot less tractable than it otherwise would be.

Thank you for answering! I appreciate the advice.

Comment: There is an answer which does a change of variables to solve the question, but also notice that the integral in the original equation has boundaries dependent on $x$ and thus you have to use a more general Leibniz integral rule, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule where there is a statement for the derivative with respect to $x$ of an integral with boundaries depending on $x$. Which will lead to a different result in your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your integral on the RHS has a closed form, which is relatively easy to find after making the substitution $t\mapsto t |f(x)|/a$ (I'll assume $a>0$). The resulting equation you obtain is
$$\pi a^2f(x)^2=\frac{f(x)^2}{a}\int_0^1\sqrt{1-t^2}dt=\frac{f(x)^2}{a}\pi/4$$
So, assuming you're not interested in the solution $f=0$ identically, the solution to your equation is $f(x)$ arbitrary but non-identically-zero and $a=2^{-2/3}.$